# Sum Column in DataGridView ignore negative numbers

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, sum

Hello I need to ignore negative numbers in a sum of a DGV column.  The code I am using to add the values is as follows:

```
private double DGVTotal()
    {
        double tot = 0;
        int i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            tot = tot + Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Total"].Value);
        }
        return tot;
    }
```

How would I change that so if the value of the Row is a negative number to not have it be included in the sum?

Thanks!

Kor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One line change:

```
tot = tot + Math.Max(0, Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Total"].Value));
```

> Look Ma! No IF! No ternary operators! Just plain Math!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
private double DGVTotal()
    {
        double tot = 0;
        int i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            Double dbTemp = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Total"].Value);
            if (dbTemp > 0)
               tot = tot + dbTemp;
        }
        return tot;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the body of the `for` loop to

```
    {
        double rowValue = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Total"].Value);
        if (rowValue > 0)
            tot += rowValue;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    double val = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Total"].Value);
    tot = tot + val > 0.0 ? val : 0.0;
}
```